# query CouchDB for Design Documents

Tags: couchdb

I have tried a couple of ways (using Fauxton with CouchDB 2.1.0) to retrieve Design documents **only**, but with no luck so far, meaning no documents returned.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong with these?

// if the document structure contains the "views" Key:

```
function (doc) {
   if(doc.views)
   emit(doc._id, doc._rev);
}
```

// if the document ID starts with "_design":

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc._id.substring(0,7) == "_design")
  emit(doc._id, doc._rev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put special keys into design doc to make it index ddocs. Please read more about those options at http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/views.html#view-options